# My Software RAID 5 has 4 3TB HDDs, now two of them have bad sectors. What is a good way to replace them?

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I run mdadm on Ubuntu 18.04 to build a RAID 5 array of 4 3TB drives several years ago. The machine was not running for years. Yesterday I powered it on and found two of the disks have a bunch of bad sectors (14000 on one, and 45000 on another). However, the RAID array can still mount. The disks are about 10 years old (produced in 2012) so I am not surprised.

Now I would like to replace the two faulty disks with new ones one-by-one and rebuild the array. Will the bad factors affect the rebuilding process? And any suggestions on what I should be careful about during the rebuild? Thanks!

Comment: You should be restoring from backups, not from the dying drives....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do, other than to rebuild the array one disk at a time.  Will the bad sectors affect the restore?  Impossible to say.  If they overlap with each other, then its possible the RAID wont be able to rebuild all the data.  However, if 3 out of the 4 disks have that sector marked as good, then it *should* be able to recover.